# How to aggregate group metrics and plot data with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, pie-chart

**I want to have a *pie chart* that compares survived people's age groups.** The problem is I don't know how to count people with the same age. As you see in the bottom of screenshot, it says 142 columns. But, there are 891 people in the dataset.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns  # for test data only

# load test data from seaborn
df_t = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

# capitalize the column headers to match code used below
df_t.columns = df_t.columns.str.title()

dft = df_t.groupby(['Age', 'Survived']).size().reset_index(name='count')

def get_num_people_by_age_category(dft):
    dft["age_group"] = pd.cut(x=dft['Age'], bins=[0,18,60,100], labels=["young","middle_aged","old"])
    return dft

# Call function
dft = get_num_people_by_age_category(dft)
print(dft)
```

output

[image]

Comment: You're getting 142 rows because of the `groubpy().size()` call. It returns a dataframe with 1 row for each unique age. If you want the original dataframe with the count next to each age, I would suggest the `pandas.merge()` function.

Comment: @Marmaduke Usually that's what [`pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) is for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `df_t.groupby(['Age', 'Survived']).size().reset_index(name='count')` creates a dataframe with one line per age and per survived status.

To get the counts per age group, an "age group" column can be added to the original dataframe. And in a next step, `groupby` can use that "age group".

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns  # to load the titanic dataset
import pandas as pd

df_t = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
df_t["age_group"] = pd.cut(x=df_t['age'], bins=[0, 18, 60, 100], labels=["young", "middle aged", "old"])

df_per_age = df_t.groupby(['age_group', 'survived']).size().reset_index(name='count')
labels = [f'{age_group},\n {"survived" if survived == 1 else "not survived"}'
          for age_group, survived in df_per_age[['age_group', 'survived']].values]
labels[-1] = labels[-1].replace('\n', ' ') # remove newline for the last items as the wedges are too thin
labels[-2] = labels[-2].replace('\n', ' ')
plt.pie(df_per_age['count'], labels=labels)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: pie plot with counts per age group]

Comment: How should we arrange to create a chart of only surviving passengers?

Comment: To limit the dataset to only the survived: `df_t = df_t[df_t["survived"] == 1]`

Answer (score 2):

- The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69887914/7758804) from [@JohanC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12046409/johanc) is great for a pie chart
- I think the data is better presented as a bar plot, so this is an alternative, which can be done with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) and `kind='bar'`.
- Reshape the data with [`pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html), which creates a frequency cross tabulation table between the two factors.
- Optionally include bar annotations using [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html)

  - See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804) for additional details about this method.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# load data
df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
df.columns = df.columns.str.title()

# map 0 and 1 of Survived to a string
df.Survived = df.Survived.map({0: 'Died', 1: 'Survived'})

# bin the age
df['Age Group'] = pd.cut(x=df['Age'], bins=[0, 18, 60, 100], labels=['Young', 'Middle Aged', 'Senior'])

# Calculate the counts
ct = pd.crosstab(df['Survived'], df['Age Group'])

# display(ct)
Age Group  Young  Middle Aged  Senior
Survived                             
Died          69          338      17
Survived      70          215       5

# plot
ax = ct.plot(kind='bar', rot=0, xlabel='')

# optionally add annotations
for c in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(c, label_type='edge')
    
# pad the spacing between the number and the edge of the figure
ax.margins(y=0.1)
```

[image]